# Root of the phone if No SDCARD is present in Phonegap

Tags: cordova

I am working with the File API of Phonegap 1.9.0. I know that the,

window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
            onFileSystemSuccess,onFileSystemError)
 will take the SDCARD as the root. But what will be the root if the device has no SDCARD?
 How to handle such situations?

Thank you,
Johncy Binoy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no SDCARD present in the phone the persistent file system path returned will be:

```
/data/data/{package name}
```

where {packate name} is the package attribute in the manifest tag in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: Excuse me, LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT points to the internal or external sdcard by default? Why it would return /data/data/{package name}